# Which is the best option to host a nettcp WCF service

Tags: iis-7, windows-services, wcf, nettcpbinding, wcf-hosting

I have a `nettcp` service which I have to host. I have three options -

1. IIS 7
2. Windows Service
3. A console application

I would be grateful if anybody could give some valuable thoughts on which option is better vis-a-vis other one.

Comment: Did my post help you arrive at any conclusions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some of my observations:

**IIS 7:**

Pros:

- Ready made hosting environment inside IIS
- Will work with pretty much any hosting environment

Cons:

- HTTP Only
- Configuration slightly more complex

**WAS:**

Pros:

- Ready made and familiar process model to that of IIS
- No dependency on IIS
- All protocols supported

Cons:

- Not all shared hosting environments will support non-http protocol bindings or unusual port numbers.
- Configuration slightly more complex

**Windows Service:**

Pros:

- Starts when windows starts
- You can start/stop the service via the service control manager
- All protocols supported

Cons:

- Some extra steps to deploy/re-deploy (installutil)
- You need some extra boilerplate code to support the service implementation
- Not ideal if you can't have access to the server to install (e.g. shared hosting)

**Console Application:**

Pros:

- Fast and simple to deploy for testing purposes
- All protocols supported

Cons:

- You need to be logged on to start the process
- Loss of session or machine shutdown will kill the service
- Console/RDP access required

Comment: Thanks Kev. I will be hosting this service in Win2008 VPS, so access wise I have complete control. Also, i wanted to know if the place where I am hosting (IIS7/WAS/ConsoleApp/WinService) impacts the performance of the service or not.?

Comment: @Saarthak - With IIS and WAS there'll possibly be a tiny overhead when the process is created depending on how you tune your idle timeout and recycling policy. But it's small potatoes.